# Extremely rare haml error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, haml, capistrano, sass

I'm currently trying to deploy an Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 app on a production server. Everything seems to be going fine untill passenger gives an 'We're sorry, but something went wrong.' error upon requesting the website.

The production log shows this error:

> Rendered sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (5.7ms)
>
> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms
>
> ActionView::Template::Error (syntax error on line 7, col 7: `'):
>
> 2:   %h2 Sign in
>   3:   = form_for( :sessions, :url => sessions_path)  do |f|
>
> 4:     .field
>
> 5:       = f.label :email
>
> 6:       %br/
>
> 7:       = f.text_field :email
>
> 8:     .field
>
> app/views/sessions/new.html.haml:5:in
>   `_app_views_sessions_new_html_haml__1068828667_250539460_0'
>        app/views/sessions/new.html.haml:3:in`
>   _app_views_sessions_new_html_haml__1068828667_250539460_0'

**Edit: Removing the f.label :email and f.label :password rows makes this error disappear, but this obviously isn't a fix **

Some information about this error:

- I develop with aptana on windows
- A co-developer who works with this project on a mac, was subject to this error a while ago, but fixed this with some unknown magic with gemsets and rvm.
- Bundle list of the production server: http://pastie.org/private/0itpfmbfwqvhpheptqz4ha
- Github repository: http://github.com/boersmamarcel/Into-Reality-Portal
- I'm deploying with capistrano 2.0 and the bundle recipe for it
- A similar error also happens on other views, but somehow this error also points to line 7 of the file, and the error message sometimes shows random strings after

  > col 7:
- I can't manage the global gemset on the production server
- Weird fact: If I remove the = f.label :password and = f.label :email rows, the error is gone :s

I would be *very* grateful if someone could help me with this. We have been working on this error for the whole day and it's driving me nuts.

Thanks
- Bas

---

Edit: the f.label function seems to be causing the problem. I uploaded a trimmed down version of the view which generated the following error: 
http://pastie.org/private/cqqipdvqod3r50x9ciwytq
This application runs succesfully on other mac-based and windows-based computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After puzzling with this error for hours and hours, it turned out the I18n gem caused this problem. 
I had a unclosed entity in my en.yml which looked like this:

```
en:
  time:
    formats:
      hourminute: "%H:%M"
  date:
```

Removing the `date:` part fixed this -in my opinion- very obscure error

Thanks to all the people who used their braincycles on this problem :)!

Answer (score 1):

If you copied the above exactly, what is the %br doing with a trailing slash? If you're rending this in HTML (not XHTML) the trailing slash is no longer valid. I don't know if it matters but sometimes the slash character throws off HAML in strange ways for me.